# Is there any way to use async await in SetState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to SetState but inside it, I have to get some data that needs async/await and I know it can't be done so I wonder if is there any way I can do it properly

codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-mendeleev-6641iw?file=/src/App.js:0-614

Edit: It's hard for me to get data before setState because If I only want to get data If the newValue satisfies a condition so Get data force to inside setState

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

  const run = async () => {
    setValue((oldValue) => {
      const newValue = [...oldValue];
      // do something makes newValue changes
      if (newValue == true) { // if newValue satisfy a condition
      const res = fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${newValue.length}`);
      const result = res.json();
      newValue.push(result.title);
      }
      return newValue;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={run}>get result</button>
      {value.map((item, index) => {
        return <h2 key={index}>{value[index]}</h2>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It should be `() => run(2)`. This isn't like HTML where you would use `run(2);` by itself.

Comment: And why you can't do that outside of the setStste callback?

Comment: You have to wait for the response *before* you can update the state

Comment: You have `value` at your disposal. `if (value === true) { // if newValue satisfies a condition` then in the if statement you can fetch data and after fetching completes you can call `setValue`: `if (value === true) { const res = await fetch(...); const result = await res.json(); setValue(result); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a React component called **Suspense**.  I think it first appeared in v16, but in all honesty I have only used it with React v18, so unsure if it will work for you.

I'll refer you to a live demo I have:  [wj-config Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reacjs-wj-config-v2-0-0-rk6h1p)

Here I use `<Suspense>` to wrap a component that requires data that is asynchronously obtained, just like when you use `fetch()`.

**Suspense** works like this:

1. It attempts to load the inner children but places a `try..catch` in said loading process.
2. If an error is caught, **and the caught error is a promise** then **Suspense** will instead render the component in its `fallback` property.
3. After rendering what's in `fallback`, React awaits the caught promise.
4. Once the caught promise resolves, **Suspense** retries rendering the child components.

I hear there are frameworks that provides the necessary mechanisms to use **Suspense** in a simple and expedite manner, but in my live demo I did it all myself.  Is not too bad I think.

The procedure to use this is:

1. Create a `readXXX` function that is a suspender function (a function that throws a promise).
2. Call this function at the beginning of your inner **Suspense** component's code.
3. Program the rest of your inner component as if the `readXXX` function has worked and returned the needed data.

Here's the code I have in the live demo to create suspender functions:

```js
function suspenderWrapper(promise) {
  let isPending = true;
  let outcome = null;
  const suspender = promise.then(
    (r) => {
      outcome = r;
      isPending = false;
    },
    (e) => {
      outcome = e;
      isPending = false;
    }
  );
  return () => {
    if (isPending) {
      throw suspender;
    }
    return outcome;
  };
}
```

Open up my live code's demo and look for **App.js** where all the magic is shown.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: It resolved the user's issue by relieving his code from needing to await the fetch call himself.

Comment: Also if you are asking because the question states "in setState", then all answers here are incorrect and the only possible answer for the user is "cannot be done".  All answers presented so far take the awaiting OUT of setState().  I just took it farther out, to the React engine itself.

Comment: You have in no way shape or form provided an answer to this question. This should **at most** be a comment, not an answer. [Stackoverflow - How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I guess you are entitled to your opinion.  The way I see it, the user can go for this approach and have the problem resolved.  Cheers.

Comment: It's not my opinion, it's stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: @Joel This looks like a fine answer to me. It does solve the problem, although in an unusual manner. Anything that is an honest attempt at answering the question that isn't low-effort is considered an answer. If you don't agree with the answer, downvotes exist.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you run first the async code, and when the data are available set the state ?

```
const run = async (x) => {
  const res = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${x}`);
  const result = await res.json();
  setValue((oldValue) => {
    // you have access to the fetched data here
    const newValue = [...oldValue];
    console.log(result.title);
    return newValue;
  });
};
```

And ofcourse the click handler should be

```
onClick={() => run(2)}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `onClick` handler be `onClick={async () => await run(2)}` in order for it to enforce and consume the async generator that's being created when calling the function? Also, there's no point in making the function async if you are not going to await anything inside of it. Should be `await fetch` and `await res.json()`. Turn on type-checking, these methods return a Promise.

Comment: @Joel correct for the async, added the `await`. For the `onClick` handler, no, there is no need to await the `run`. There is not generator involved here. And you do not want to do anything with the return value of the `run`.

Comment: While it is not necessary, and sure, let's say it's a matter of coding preference. I'd argue that explicitly declaring functionality vs. implicit 
happenstance vagueness functionality is a bad one to enforce. When this code gets refractored in the future and happens to return something, then what? Following the async/await practise will ensure less headache for everyone in such (if not all) scenarios.

Comment: I've edited the question you can check out

Answer (score 1):

You can get the old value from the `value` variable which is always storing the current state, and do the `if` check on it instead.

And if the `if` condition on `value` was true - then you can call `fetch` and after that call `setState` and update the state.

If the condition was not true, there is **no need** to update the state since it stayed the same.
See the code below:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

const run = async () => {
      
  //some condition on the current value
  if (value) {
    const res = await fetch( `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${newValue.length}`);
    const result = await res.json();

    // And here apply the changes on the state
    setValue((oldValue) => {
      const newValue = [...oldValue];
      newValue.push(result.title);
      return newValue;
    });
  }

  //Outside the if block - no need to change the state.
};
```

Comment: I've edited the question you can check out

Comment: You have the old value of the state in the ```value``` variable - this value is storing the state, so you don't have to get it inside the ```setState``` function.

Comment: Edited the answer according to your question.